# Filter data points on line chart without restricting x-axis range

Tags: powerbi

I am stuck on an issue in which I just want to display the x-axis in my line chart and I don't want to display the values.

Below image is how it is getting displayed
[image: Line Chart]

This data gets populated when I select the value 3 in my slicer I want just to see the line drawn for x-axis value of 21,22,23.

For the rest, I just want to see in x-axis but don't want to see the line drawn for it. On the x-axis, the hour is displayed which shows the value of incoming data for each hour. As I don't want to see any incoming data for 00,01,02,03,04,05 hours just want to see it in x-axis don't want to see the value of it. How can I restrict the chart to draw the line for just 21,22,23?

Tried a visual filter but using that the x-axis 00,01,02,03,04 does not get displayed in the x-axis.

This is the image if I use a visual filter, but that is not what I want. I want time frame (x-axis) to be displayed )
[image: With Filter]

As I want those in x-axis but the line should not be displayed on top of it.

For example, something like this:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but something of a workaround...

You can create a measure that only displays for the subset you want an then plot that on top of the original line, which you can to be white or whatever your background color is. I've set it as a light grey to visualize the concept better.

[image: Line Chart]

The measure would look something similar to this:

```
= IF(MAX(Table[hour]) IN {"21", "22", "23"}, COUNT(Table[Ok]), BLANK())
```

Comment: Your solution helped me, Thank you so much!!